# selecting a column value based on a different column value after applying Groupby

Tags: python, group-by, dataframe

i am able to get this to work, but not after I apply a groupby.  in this example I simply want to have the last column contain the lowest value from column x.  I have popuymated the df with a column called yminx with is what I would like my abc column to look like.  I can't get the value of abc to be the local (after groupby) min.

```
In [3]:

df
Out[3]:
   Symbol   x   y  yminx
0     IBM  12  27     58
1     IBM   1  58     58
2     IBM  13  39     58
3     IBM   4  45     58
4      GS   5  72     44
5      GS  15  54     44
6      GS  20  50     44
7      GS   4  90     44
8      GS  14  39     44
9      GS   2  44     44
10     GS   7  79     44
11     GS  12  27     44
12     GS  11  66     44

df['try']=df.groupby(['Symbol'])['x'].transform('min')
df['cond1'] = df['x'] == min(df['x'])                     
df['abc']= np.select(df['cond1'],df['y'])


    Symbol   x   y  yminx  cond1  abc  try
0     IBM  12  27     58  False   58    1
1     IBM   1  58     58   True   58    1
2     IBM  13  39     58  False   58    1
3     IBM   4  45     58  False   58    1
4      GS   5  72     90  False   58    2
5      GS  15  54     90  False   58    2
6      GS  20  50     90  False   58    2
7      GS   4  90     90  False   58    2
8      GS  14  39     90  False   58    2
9      GS   2  44     90  False   58    2
10     GS   7  79     90  False   58    2
11     GS  12  27     90  False   58    2
12     GS  11  66     90  False   58    2
```

In the output i see 58 being selected which is the nin for IBM but when I get to GS the same min is carried over as if the groupby was never referenced

I am sure it's just a syntax thing but i am stuck.

thanks for any help

John

Comment: yes, that was a manual error on my part, i have corrected the output and added the groupby line, sorry for the sloppy work on my end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to work with the *indices* of the minimum values.  For example:

```
>>> imin = df.groupby("Symbol")["x"].transform("idxmin")
>>> df["yminx"] = df.loc[imin, "y"].values
>>> df
   Symbol   x   y  yminx
0     IBM  12  27     58
1     IBM   1  58     58
2     IBM  13  39     58
3     IBM   4  45     58
4      GS   5  72     44
5      GS  15  54     44
6      GS  20  50     44
7      GS   4  90     44
8      GS  14  39     44
9      GS   2  44     44
10     GS   7  79     44
11     GS  12  27     44
12     GS  11  66     44
```

(The `values` is needed because the result of the `df.loc` has its own index, and we want to ignore that and only care about the values instead.)